# No longer able to use the APIs, both Analytics GetRequest.Execute() or Directory GetRequest.Execute() just hang after updating nuget packages

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

Sadly I'm no longer to use the API since updating the nuget packages to the latest. I had GA and then added Directory, code was update and this no longer works, the code just hangs once .Execute() is called. I tried rolling as much of the code back to the original DLLs, but this seems impossible. I also tried looking for logs on the developers console dashboard, but I don't even think it's possible to see anything. There are no error thrown locally, the app simply doesn't run. I've left it running for over 15 minutes, and nothing. I also tried re-generating the certificate, and nothing.

I've had the problem before when I first added Google authentication to the project, and had to pull an older version of the code (which works), and start again. But now I have to add more functionality to the site, and the minute I do it, i.e. Directory API, everything stops working, including the Analytics API which also hangs.

I know other people have had this same issue, but simply put, no one could figure out what happened and then proceeded to build a console app to run in parallel, or abandoned the project. This sadly won't work for me, and I would rather find a solution than rely on hacks. There's clearly something wrong with the new nuget packages, or perhaps the documentation needs updating?

Can anyone please help?

I use the following for credentials:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(AppSettings.GoogleApplication_ServiceAccountEmail)
{
    Scopes = scopes
}.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

And the below for connecting to the Directory API:

```
var service = new DirectoryService(GoogleBaseClientServiceInitialiserFactory.New(new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupMember }));
var getRequest = service.Members.Get(AppSettings.GoogleGroupKey, userEmailAddress);
var result = getRequest.Execute();
```

Comment: I think that we introduced this bug in 1.9.3.  We are on it - https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/606. Sorry!!!

Comment: Is there a work around? Maybe a different way of accessing data from GA or Directory?

Comment: Just to confirm that reverting the code back to 1.9.2 fixes for me. Anyone trying to also never the code will need to all related dependentAssembly from any app.config AND web.config files as bindingRedirect will try and force to use 1.9.3 if once upgraded.

Comment: We are on it. I saw that you posted details in the issue how to reproduce it, so I'm going to do so later on today. Thanks and sorry

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate thread, see [Google Calendar API - Not Returning From Execute() C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618284/google-calendar-api-not-returning-from-execute-c-sharp) for more information.

You can compile and run the latest code form the GitHub repository.

And then, download the Analytics code (https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/analytics/v3/csharp). It's better to download it yourself, since you are going to avoid tons of binding redirects that might not work. More details about how to do so are available at https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/606.

As explained in the dup SO thread, we are planning to release in the next few weeks a new version with the fix. Stay tuned!